# using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Claims; fails in my Home controller!

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, claims-based-identity, federated-identity, wif

I'm following the [Microsoft guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff359105.aspx) for implementing federated identities.  As it doesn't state where the code should be placed I created a file `\App_Code\Auth.cs` for it.  when it's time to implement the `FederationResult` to my home controller I try to use the aforementioned namespace but VS complains of missing an assembly reference.

The weird thing is that the code in `Auth.cs` doesn't complain... I've looked in the `References` item of the project and don't see anything I can recognise, although I did "Add STS reference" to the project. I've also looked in NuGet but don't see anything I should add...

what's going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hmm... seems I just needed to add the reference manually.  I don't know how come the assembly is available to some pieces of the code and not to others but it works!

One more thing, I needed to use `Microsoft.IdentityModel.Web` not `.Claims`